# Class instances passed to ConcurrentStack.Push vanish?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, stack, queue

**EDIT: TL;DR** `ConcurrentStack.Push` is not playing nice in a multithreaded environment and I am clueless as to why.

### Summary

After trying to write a "custom `ThreadPool`", dubbed the "`ThreadFactory`", I started to stumble into some peculiar issues.

Namely, `ConcurrentStack.Push` *seems to not always* push the passed parameter to the stack.

### Source

**ThreadFactory.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace CustomThreadFactory
{
    public class ThreadFactory
    {
        public uint Working
        {
            get
            {
                return (uint)( _numWorkers - _available.Count );    // Returns how many workers are currently busy
            }

            set { }
        }

        private uint _numWorkers;                                   // Stores the amount of workers

        private ConcurrentStack<ThreadWorker> _available;           // Stores the available workers
        private ConcurrentQueue<ThreadTask> _backlog;               // ThreadTask backlog, ThreadTasks queue up here if there're no workers available

        public ThreadFactory( uint numWorkers = 8 )
        {
            _numWorkers = numWorkers;

            _available = new ConcurrentStack<ThreadWorker>();
            _backlog = new ConcurrentQueue<ThreadTask>();

            for ( uint i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++ )
                _available.Push( new ThreadWorker( this ) );        // Populate worker stack
        }

        public bool Continue( ThreadWorker sender, ref ThreadTask task )
        {                                                           // This function is called by ThreadWorker to decide whether it should lock next call
            if( _backlog.Count > 0 )                                // More work available = Do not lock, a new ThreadTask has been set
            {
                while ( !_backlog.TryDequeue( out task ) ) ;        // Busy-wait TryDequeue on the backlog queue, this should only take a couple cycles (if not one)
                return false;                                       // ThreadWorker._lockThread boolean is set to false here, it won't lock next cycle
            }
            else
            {
                task = null;                                        // No more tasks available, last task is marked for GC
                _available.Push( sender );                          // Push the worker back onto the available stack

                return true;                                        // ThreadWorker._lockThread boolean is set to true here, the worker thread will now lock and wait
            }
        }

        public void Enqueue( ThreadTask task )
        {
            if( _available.Count > 0 )                              // If there's a worker available (and sleeping/locked), wake them and pass the new task
            {
                ThreadWorker worker;
                while ( !_available.TryPop( out worker ) ) ;        // Busy-wait TryPop on worker stack, this should only take a couple cycles (if not one)

                worker.Wake( task );
            }
            else                                                    // Otherwise this task will be added to the backlog queue
            {
                _backlog.Enqueue( task );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ThreadWorker.cs**

```cs
using System.Threading;

namespace CustomThreadFactory
{
    public class ThreadWorker
    {
        private ThreadFactory _factory;         // Parent ThreadFactory

        private volatile bool _lockThread;      // Should lock on next cycle?
        private object _threadLock;             // Locking object
        private Thread _thread;                 // Worker thread

        private ThreadTask _task;               // Current task

        public ThreadWorker( ThreadFactory parent )
        {
            _factory = parent;

            _lockThread = true;
            _threadLock = new object();

            _thread = new Thread( _Work );
            _thread.Start();
        }

        ~ThreadWorker()
        {
            _thread?.Abort();                   // If _thread is "valid", _thread.Abort
            _threadLock = null;                 // Mark for GC (not sure if required)
        }

        private void _Work()
        {
            while( true )
            {
                if ( _lockThread )
                    lock ( _threadLock )
                        Monitor.Wait( _threadLock );
                // ---

                _task?.Run();                   // If _task is "valid", _task.Run

                                                // If _factory has more tasks, _task will be set and _lockThread will be false
                                                // Otherwise the worker thread will lock on the next cycle
                _lockThread = _factory.Continue( this, ref _task );
            }
        }

        public void Wake( ThreadTask task )
        {
            _task = task;                       // Set _task
            _lockThread = false;                // Don't lock the thread unless the ThreadFactory specifically "says so"

            lock ( _threadLock )
                Monitor.Pulse( _threadLock );   // Unlock if currently locked
        }
    }
}
```

**ThreadTask.cs**

```cs
namespace CustomThreadFactory
{
    public delegate void ThreadAction( object parameters );

    public class ThreadTask
    {
        private ThreadAction _action;               // Delegate action
        private object _parameters;                 // Object parameter(s)

        public ThreadTask( ThreadAction action )    // Parameterless constructor
        {
            _action = action;
            _parameters = null;
        }

        public ThreadTask( ThreadAction action, object parameters )
        {
            _action = action;
            _parameters = parameters;
        }

        public void Run()                          // Executes the delegate, passing the stored parameters (or null)
        {
            _action( _parameters );
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
namespace CustomThreadFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            ThreadFactory f = new ThreadFactory();

            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();

            for ( uint i = 0; i < 512; i++ )
            {
                f.Enqueue( new ThreadTask( ( object parameters ) =>
                {
                    for ( uint x = 0; x < 2048; x++ )
                    {
                        long y = (long)Math.Pow( x, 2 );
                    }
                } ) );
            }

            while ( f.Working > 0 )
                Thread.Sleep( 1 );

            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "Took {0}ms", s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds - 1 ) );

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

### Issue

The problem seems to lie within `ThreadFactory.Continue`, if `_backlog.Count > 0` is not met, the `ThreadWorker sender` is supposed to be *re*added to the *available workers stack*.
Though this doesn't always happen. (Implying that *sometimes* it does *re*add all the `ThreadWorker`s successfully)

**I have tried:**

- Debug vs. Release (no difference)
- Console.WriteLine( "Thread now available" ) in `ThreadWorker.Continue`, always prints the correct amount of lines (default 8), though not all `ThreadWorker`s are pushed to the *available workers stack*
- **EDIT:** `lock( _stackLock )` around `_available.Push( sender )` (no difference)

From here on I can't really see what's causing the `ConcurrentStack` to not push the `ThreadWorker`s back on to the *available workers stack*.
A helping hand would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Though nice, your post is arguably too verbose and could be reduced to reflect the immediate problem rather than show us your threading manager

Comment: @MickyD The reason for my post being this verbose is that I have only a slight suspicion why this is exactly happening, but my suspicion could be far off, making the reproduction of this issue difficult by reducing to just the reflection of the problem at hand. The "Structure" part is there to address "what, why, how (does this...)"; though I must still agree with your statement.

Comment: A suggestion - hopefully helpful - it's a good idea to break this up into smaller classes and smaller methods so that you can write unit tests and know for sure that each part works. Otherwise what can happen is that you tweak it enough to get it to do what you expect, but at that part it's hard to actually know why it's working. And even then it might seem to work but then not work later because of some race condition. When something gets this complex unit testing is vital so that you can "prove" to yourself that your code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some race conditions and there is a problem with the `Monitor.Lock` / `Monitor.Pulse`. I changed some of your code to get it basicly working;

Changes in `ThreadFactory`

```
public class ThreadFactory
{
    ...

    public ThreadTask Continue( ThreadWorker sender )
    {
        if ( _backlog.Count > 0 )
        {
            ThreadTask task;
            do
            {
                if ( _backlog.TryDequeue( out task ) )
                {
                    return task;
                }
            }
            while ( _backlog.Count > 0 );
        }

        _available.Push( sender );
        return null;

    }

    public void Enqueue( ThreadTask task )
    {
        if ( _available.Count > 0 )                              // If there's a worker available (and sleeping/locked), wake them and pass the new task
        {
            ThreadWorker worker;
            do
            {
                if ( _available.TryPop( out worker ) )
                {
                    worker.Wake( task );
                }
            }
            while ( _available.Count > 0 );        // Busy-wait TryPop on worker stack, this should only take a couple cycles (if not one)
        }
        else                                                    // Otherwise this task will be added to the backlog queue
        {
            _backlog.Enqueue( task );
        }
    }
}
```

and the whole `ThreadWorker`

```
public class ThreadWorker
{
    private ThreadFactory _factory;         // Parent ThreadFactory

    private AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent( false );
    private Thread _thread;                 // Worker thread
    private volatile ThreadTask _task;               // Current task

    public ThreadWorker( ThreadFactory parent, string name = null )
    {
        Name = name;

        _factory = parent;

        _thread = new Thread( _Work );
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    ~ThreadWorker()
    {
        _thread?.Abort();                   // If _thread is "valid", _thread.Abort
    }

    private void _Work()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            _event.WaitOne();
            _task?.Run();                   // If _task is "valid", _task.Run

            // If _factory has more tasks, _task will be set and _lockThread will be false
            // Otherwise the worker thread will lock on the next cycle
            Wake( _factory.Continue( this ) );
        }
    }

    public void Wake( ThreadTask task )
    {
        _task = task;
        if ( _task != null )
        {
            _event.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making me realize that I had a race condition! I reviewed my usage of `Monitor.Wait` / `Monitor.Pulse` and saw what was wrong there. I have restructured `TryDequeue` / `TryPop` code as you advised, but fixed and kept the `Monitor` code due to its low overhead, thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956127/threading-problem-with-monitor-wait-and-monitor-pulse). All seems to be working well now!

Comment: The `if  (_backlog.Count > 0 )` isn't necessary, you can directly call `if ( _backlog.TryDequeue(out task))`. No need for a loop either: if `TryDequeue` failed, it always means that the queue is empty (the loop is already implemented inside of `TryDequeue`)